# IntelliJ not showing me the differences between branch and master

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have used IntelliJ to push changes to my master branch. Another dev created another branch, I'm trying to pick and choose changes, however I'm not able to view their changes.
I have used git > Repository > branches > Show Diff with Working Tree.
But when I click on the files that are different, all it shows me is the 'Base Version' on the left with nothing on the right. What's going on?

Comment: Have you run `git fetch` or the equivalent in IntelliJ?

Comment: @GaëlJ git fetch didn't' work, same problem.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using?

Comment: ULTIMATE 2020.1

Comment: Could you please share additional screenshots of your issue? 
Do you compare it with origin/another-dev-branch?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to see changes between two commits you need to select only those two commits in the `Git` windows in IntelliJ and press right click `Compare Versions`.

Comment: I'm trying to compare with my local (master) with the branch. I choose the file,  right click > Git > Compare with Branch > <branch>, just shows me my file: master (local) with nothing on the right side.